# Executable file doesn't run on Windows even with the .exe extension

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I finally finished my app and I swear there is nothing to do I tried everything, even to change the tools of Vmware (I worked on linux and I wanted to drag my .exe file on the windows window, which did not work) So I opted for another solution. Finally I have finally my file on windows and I already find something strange it is in the form of a file and not executable while I had done `pyinstaller -F -w script.py` before (I had also already installed pyinstaller and everything else) Well no matter I decide then to change the file into .exe and an error appears "This application can not run on your Desktop, To find a version for your Desktop ask the software publisher" What to do? I'm not going to have to retype everything on Windows and not on Linux, that would be much too long and I would have to reinstall everything!

**There's a simple solution to fix that ?**

**EDIT :**

Here's the error message =>

[image: problem]

And I tried pyinstaller and auto-py-to-exe (with Windows based and Console based for Linux) And it still not work I really don't know what's going on

Comment: try auto-py-to-exe to bundle your exe and see if that isolates pyinstaller as your issue

Comment: Just tried it, Auto-py-to-exe doesn't work and doesn't work on Linux even if it's console based

Comment: “PyInstaller is tested against Windows, MacOS X, and Linux. However, it is not a cross-compiler; to make a Windows app you run PyInstaller on Windows, and to make a Linux app you run it on Linux, etc. x PyInstaller has been used successfully with AIX, Solaris, FreeBSD and OpenBSD but testing against them is not part of our continuous integration tests, and the development team offers no guarantee (all code for these platforms comes from external contributions) that PyInstaller will work on these platforms or that they will continue to be supported.“ -https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/

Comment: Thus there is no fix. Bundle on windows next time

Comment: If it's created without a .exe extension, that's because it's _not an .exe file_. Linux executables and Windows executables have different formats (PE vs ELF), link to different libraries, etc; you can't make one into the other just by renaming it.

Comment: So what am I supposed to do?

Comment: I will have to copy and paste all my code from Vmware to windows and reinstall everything there? Like pip for example? Or pyinstaller ?